# Class Properties not showing in footer

Tags: html, css

I was doing research and found out that you are only supposed to have one `<body>` tag, which after learning that I proceeded to clean up my code because I had 3 different set of body tags and by removing the tags to where I only had one set I messed it up to where it no longer aligns my footer properly.
Sorry if this is a silly issue, I am 15 and I started learning html 3 days ago at this point.

I have tried putting the footer outside of the boundary of the `<body>` tag and tried putting the class within a div tag right after the first footer tag.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <title> Hub </title>
  <h2 style="text-align:center">Home</h2>
<p style="text-align:center"> Welcome to my test website.
<i><b><br> (Currently Under construction) </b></i>
</p>
<p> </p>
<p style="text-align:center">
  <a href="https://youtube.com">
    <img border=0 src="youtube.png" width="100" height="70"> </a>
</p>
<p></p>
<p class="center">
<img src="razer.jpg" width="640" height=360>
</p>
<br>
<footer class="footer">
  <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Home </a>
  <a href="about.html" style="text-decoration:none"> About </a>
  <a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Contact </a>
  <a href="projects.html" style="text-decoration:none"> Projects </a>
</footer>
</body>
</html>

Here is the css class
.footer {
  background-color: white;
  color: Orange;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I expected it to stay aligned with the center, but it ended up reverting to text with no alignment.

Comment: Did you mean `text-align:center` instead of `align-items: center`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

Here's a little jsFiddle to help simplify the code a bit - and just to show you how that works.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5Lros2h4/

Here's the basic HTML structure:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
      .site-footer {
        border: 1px solid red;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Header stuff</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <p>Stuff</p>
    </main>

    <footer class="site-footer">
      <nav class="main-menu">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

You'll spend most of your time in the `body` - and like you said - you wouldn't have more than one of those tags.

I suggest you keep you css in the css file - or in the styles tag in the head.

For your question - we basically just need to see this in order to help:

```
<footer class="site-footer">
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Your `align-items: center` is a flex-box declaration. You might mean `text-align: center`

Check out these resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Learn about the box-model and the `display` types first - and then `position` and you'll be on the right path. Join a chat-room for something like CSS https://discord.gg/pFc6XmH

and later... when you're feeling ready - watch this: https://flexbox.io

Keep your examples as simple as possible and you'll get the most help. : )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually what you mean, but if you want to make the a-tag to be in the middle, you can use

```
footer{text-align:center;}
```

But if you want to make each of your a-tag to be separated and in the middle. you should just make the a-tag a block element. You can put it by adding in css

```
a{ display:block; }
```